# Most readable way to insert variable into curly braces in Ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, jinja2, curly-braces

I'm trying to use the loop feature to set the following lines in a config file:

```php
$nrconf{kernelhints} = 0;
$nrconf{ucodehints} = 0;
```

The code below fails with "jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: unexpected '}'".

```yaml
- name: disable kernelhints on apt install
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/needrestart/needrestart.conf
    regexp: '^.*\$nrconf\{{{ item }}\}.*$'
    line: '$nrconf\{{{ item }}\} = 0;'
  loop:
    - 'kernelhints'
    - 'ucodehints'
```

I understand that I can use either `{% raw %}` or `{{ '{' }}{{ item }}` or `{{ '{' + item }}` approach, but the resulting code look makes me sad. Is there any trick to make the code clean and clear?

Answer (score 3):

You could use string formatting:

```yaml
    - name: disable kernelhints on apt install
      lineinfile:
        path: needrestart.conf
        regexp: '{{ "^.*\$nrconf{%s}.*$" % item }}'
        line: '{{ "$nrconf{%s} = 0" % item }}'
      loop:
        - 'kernelhints'
        - 'ucodehints'
```

I think that's a little more clear.

When writing this sort of thing for myself, I try to avoid nested quotes and instead use some of YAML's quote operators, like this:

```yaml
    - name: disable kernelhints on apt install
      lineinfile:
        path: needrestart.conf
        regexp: >-
          {{ "^.*\$nrconf{%s}.*$" % item }}
        line: >-
          {{ "$nrconf{%s} = 0" % item }}
      loop:
        - 'kernelhints'
        - 'ucodehints'
```

Operationally it's identical, but it removes one level of quoting so that you don't go insane if you need nested quotes *inside* your expression.

Comment: Nice approach. Thanks a lot)

Answer (score 1):

In *regexp*, put the braces into brackets. In *line*, concatenate the strings

```yaml
        regexp: '^.*\$nrconf[{]{{ item }}[}].*$'
        line: "{{ '$nrconf{' ~ item ~ '} = 0;' }}"
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:

    - name: disable kernelhints on apt install
      lineinfile:
        path: /tmp/needrestart.conf
        regexp: '^.*\$nrconf[{]{{ item }}[}].*$'
        line: "{{ '$nrconf{' ~ item ~ '} = 0;' }}"
      loop:
        - kernelhints
        - ucodehints
```

For example, given the file

```bash
shell> cat /tmp/needrestart.conf 
$nrconf{undef} = 0;
```

The playbook gives running with *--check --diff* options

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -CD

PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************

TASK [disable kernelhints on apt install] ****************************************************
--- before: /tmp/needrestart.conf (content)
+++ after: /tmp/needrestart.conf (content)
@@ -1 +1,2 @@
 $nrconf{undef} = 0;
+$nrconf{kernelhints} = 0;

changed: [localhost] => (item=kernelhints)
--- before: /tmp/needrestart.conf (content)
+++ after: /tmp/needrestart.conf (content)
@@ -1 +1,2 @@
 $nrconf{undef} = 0;
+$nrconf{ucodehints} = 0;

changed: [localhost] => (item=ucodehints)

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost: ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

The result

```bash
shell> cat /tmp/needrestart.conf 
$nrconf{undef} = 0;
$nrconf{kernelhints} = 0;
$nrconf{ucodehints} = 0;
```